# NG build takes too long, can VS code be used to avoid?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am creating an Angular 4 application, and everytime ng build takes about 45 seconds even for a very small change. I am wondering how to avoid this by having an auto compile in VS Code IDE, so that my changes would reflect immediately in 'dist' folder and I can directly go test on the browser. Or any other alternative to save this time would be a great help.

Comment: If you are still developing then why are you not running `ng serve` for the development server instead?

Comment: I have node.js as backend,so I do  ng build && node server.js

Comment: You know you can actually set a proxy through to the backend from the dev server. Or simply point to the alternate server address during development. Point is the dev server is made for fast refresh. The build process is not.

Comment: See [Proxy To Backend](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) in the @angular/cli documentation

Comment: build for dev you can use `-dev` flag instead of `-prd`. dev build does not include aot flag by default.